# Random VSTS Build Errors - Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '-1'.

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a medium sized ASP.NET MVC4 solution with about 15 projects in it. I have been using a paid Hosted Pipeline (VS 2017) in VSTS for my builds. Although I keep getting the error below, randomly in the build or package steps. Re-run the build and it will pass with no other changes made in source code! No other errors, details errors are shown in the build log. And it occurs randomly in any of the project in the solution. Any idea what could be causing it or how to get more info on the error to avoid it?

### [error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '-1'.

Comment: How did you define your build definition? If you build the 15 projects separately, do you use msbuild task or vs build task? And it would be better if you can give more detail build logs.

Comment: I just had the same thing happen to me.  I'm using a VS build task.  Just like Sanddy says, that's the only thing in the logs that shows an error.

Comment: 2017-04-28T13:54:29.7639535Z   Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn
2017-04-28T13:54:29.9719572Z ##[error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '-1'.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT I am building the solution using the Visual Studio Build task. I am using VS 2017 to build the project locally. 
So all projects get built together in release config, using x64 platform. I am passing the /m switch to the solution file to make sure it uses all cores of the Hosted Pipeline. The same project, will build correctly if its queued again without any changes to the source. 

Is there a private email id where I can email the logs since I can't post them publicly as they contain info private to my project.

Comment: also getting this (on self hosted vsts agent). Wondering if there is a vsts issue.

Comment: @Sanddy since SO is not allowed to show private email here, so you can give the log as screenshot and shelter the parts which are private. Beside, please make sure you are build `.sln` not `.csproj` for **visual studio build** task. If you wan to build `.csproj` separately, you should use **MSBuild** task.

Comment: @Darthg8r What's your project type? And what's the build definition settings for VS build task?

Comment: @marina here is the  screenshot [![buildfail.png](https://s17.postimg.org/72pw5rcbj/buildfail.png)](https://postimg.org/image/6d73tebrv/)

I am building the sln file using the VS task. This is just one of the errors, I have several others where MSbuild error has come up. Everytime in a different place.

Comment: @Sanddy Can you give more detail logs by setting `system.debug`=`true` in variables Tab?

Comment: below is one of the build errors in debug mode. The full log can't be pasted because it has project details. Not sure if this is any helpful.

(Error Log)[https://pastebin.com/029qc5GK ].

To add further, the same build no source changes rebuild successfully in the next run. So something weird is happening.

Comment: What's the error message in the "MSBuild_*.failure.txt" file?

Comment: also getting this on our build agents on Visual Studio Team services
There are no error line items anywhere, but at the end it says [error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '-1'.

It is also intermittent, although the frequency has increased recently

Comment: We are experiencing the same issues with the VS2017 hosted agent. Only that ##[error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '-1'. No other errors. We are using the Visual Studio Build -task and building the sln-file.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT we are using Hosted VS2017 pipeline. How to access the MSBuild_*.failure.txt file? I tried the download all logs but dont find that file. Where do I get it from? yesterday about 4-5 builds failed with the same error. Its frustrating!

Comment: @Sanddy Add a copy and pubish artifact task in your build definition to publish the file so that you can check it. The file is placed in the temp folder and the temp folder on Hosted VS2017 agent is usually C:\a\\_temp or D:\a\\_temp.

Comment: As additional information, we are also getting a similar error with unit tests: ##[error]System.Exception: VSTest Test Run failed with exit code: -1

Comment: @AnttiSimonen  could you ping me on twitter with some information about your account URLs.  We at seeing  a few reports of this had the intermittent nature makes it challenging to reproduce.

Comment: @Sanddy can you ping me on twitter with some information about your account URL.  We are seeing a few reports of this issue and are having a hard time tracking it down.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson it seems some fix was pushed on Hosted Pipelines, In past 2-3 days I have not been getting any errors. Will tweet you if I encounter errors again. Thanks.

Comment: We are still getting errors but mostly with VSTest and not with MSBuild anymore. The errors are becoming more rare though, but still occur daily.

Comment: If you are seeing this error. Could you add an always run PowerShell task to the end of your build with this script 

Get-EventLog -LogName Application -After ([datetime]::now.addhours(-1)) -Source 'Process Exit Monitor' | % { "EventID: $($_.EventID)" ; "TimeGenerated: $($_.TimeGenerated)" ; "Message: $($_.Message)" ; "" }

And post the result here https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/4280

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have finally identified the issue and are working on rolling out an updated image with a mitigation.  It turns out that the automatic update feature for VSIX extensions runs as a scheduled task in Windows.  When this process starts it will terminate all process for executables that exist under the Visual Studio install directory.  We are rolling out an image that turns off this scheduled task.  I appreciate the patience as we worked to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft is [investigating this right now](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/4256). It seems to be tied to another issue that crashes vstest as well.

A temporary suggested workaround (I haven't tried this myself) as reported in that thread:

> For a temporary work around if you add a second vsbuild task right after the first one and set the first to continue on error it seems to complete successfully 100% of the time.